# Skip slides when going back - Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a lot of slides with lists that use either `pause` or `<number>` after item so that they are shown at different times. Some slides have up to 9 different stages for it, so after I am done presenting and someone needs to go to a slide at the beginning it will be a hassle to go through all of them.

Is there a way so that if I am going in the reverse order in the pdf, once I reach a slide that has multiple stages it will go to the frame before and skip all the in-between moments?

I found a lot of questions/answers that would use `hyperref` to skip  to specific sections, but I just want so that when I am going back it will skip all the unnecessary steps.

Is that way the only way to do it? I am using metropolis theme and it doesn't have buttons at the bottom of the slide.

Thanks!

Comment: Something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413375/121799 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can bring back the navigation symbols to any theme which removed them like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[horizontal]

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
  abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could modify the metropolis theme to have navigation symbols.

Comment out line 106.

https://github.com/matze/mtheme/blob/master/source/beamerouterthememetropolis.dtx

Comment: The `.dtx` file is not the one loaded by `beamer`, so changing that file won't do anything (and it's not recommended to change package code).